# About the electromagnet

Tags: power-supply

How much of electricity is required for 700 gram of copper wire with a thickness of 32 gauge, to make it into a strong electromagnet ?

Comment: For a *strong* electromagnet *much* electricity is required.

Comment: What is the core material and cross-section area?

Comment: Define "strong" ...

Answer (score 5):

With a heat capacity of 24.4 J/mol.k, and an atomic weight of 65, 700g of copper will have a heat capacity of 262J/k. That means if you want a 50C temperature rise (75C should be reasonably safe for most insulation types), you can apply a single pulse of 13kJ. That's 13kW for one second, or 1.3kW for 10 seconds.

This is the so-called adiabatic mode of operation of the coil, where the heat is absorbed in the mass of the copper, and none is lost to the environment. Of course you can apply only a single pulse, and must wait until the coil cools down before applying the next one.

If you want to run for longer periods, then you can start to figure in the loss of heat to the environment. Unfortunately estimating the heat loss of the surface of an object is more difficult, there aren't simple figures available like there are for heat capacity.

700g of copper is about the size of an apple. I'd estimate you could probably lose 10W (give or take a factor of 3?) from that sort of surface while keeping the temperature reasonable. Of course when wound on an iron core, there is more surface area available for heat dissipation. It's a case of measure the temperature rise of the target if you want good figures.

Comment: This answer is the cleverest one I have ever seen in EESE. It is a pinpoint answer to the question and do not give a slightest hint for the unasked details -  for example how to actually get the strongest force per used watt from that 700g..

Comment: I actually made a magnet this way a couple of decades ago, to calibrate a Hall sensor, or rather its linearity. What was the strongest field I could generate in an air-cored coil, if I could read the meter fast enough. My limiting temperature was 'not much smoke comes off', and I built a sample and hold, to be able to use a half second pulse.